# Fixing Evil inside Emacs terminal mode

Tags: evil, terminal-emacs, term

I use Evil mode inside Emacs to emulate vim-style editing. In the Xwindows based graphical user interface of Emacs on Ubuntu 16.04, Evil mode works perfectly.

When I launch emacs in terminal mode with `emacs -nw foobar.cpp` ,say I want to save a file with `M-: w` then I get the message in the message buffer saying `M-: is not defined`

However, the standard C-x C-s method of saving a file works in the terminal. How do I get the `M-:` behavior working in Emacs terminal mode as it does in graphical mode?

Comment: What's your terminal emulator? Chances are you don't get this in all terminal emulators and depending on the specific terminal emulator, you'll get different issues.

Comment: @wasamasa I use guake and terminator on Ubuntu 16.04, alongside the zshell.

Comment: @wasamasa It seems the problem happens when I am using Emacs from inside of a tmux session. When tmux is not on, then M-: works as intended.

Comment: That aside, `M-:` isn't a command defined by Evil. This would only be Evil-related if enabling Evil would trigger this and `M-:` worked fine otherwise...